# Brownie doesnt compile but says it did

Tags: solidity, brownie, compiler

if i run `brownie compile` i get INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s). Brownie v1.19.0 - Python development framework for Ethereum

Project has been compiled. Build artifacts saved at C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Documenten\demo\build\contracts

but its not in there

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried a variety of approaches to force brownie to compile my code.  There was no error.  I just did not produce anything even though the output of the compile command indicated compilation had completed.

When else does `brownie compile` say it succeeded but nothing happens?  When there is nothing in the `contracts` directory.

**Solution:**

It turns out that I had created my Solidity contract file with a `.Sol` contract extension instead of `.sol`.  Compilation succeeded without any issue once I renamed the file to have a lower-case 's' in the extension.

**The lesson:**

brownie is looking for files in the `contracts` folder with all lower-case `.sol` as a filename extension.  If there is nothing in the `contracts folder` or no file with a lower-case `.sol` filename extension, brownie will say it compiled successfully but really do nothing.

Comment: Are you a human being? It is a too long answer, just to suggest checking the files extension to be .sol.

Comment: Sorry I'm too verbose for you.  Some people like to draw stick-people, others like to paint complete pictures.  I wasn't just giving narrow facts, but the background as well.  Are you a troll?